# Why do I only get 1 pin on the map when I have created 2?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

I have a geocoder and I try with that one create pins on my map, but with my code I only manage to get 1 pin on the map.. my code:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();

        var possibleAddresses = await gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync ("Adress1");
        foreach (var address in possibleAddresses) {


            var pin = new Pin ();
            pin.Position = new Position (address.Latitude, address.Longitude);
            pin.Label = "test1";
            pin.Address = "test1";

            theMap.Pins.Add (pin);

        }

        var possibleAddresses2 = await gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync ("Adress2");
        foreach (var address2 in possibleAddresses) {


            var pin = new Pin();
            pin.Position = new Position (address2.Latitude, address2.Longitude);
            pin.Label = "test2";
            pin.Address = "test2";

            pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;

            theMap.Pins.Add(pin);


        }
```

it only shows my first adress and not the second one when I type in 2 different adresses.

Comment: If that is not a typo, then you are iterating the same list at both time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the results from the first GeoCoder call in both loops, so the same pin is being added twice

```
foreach (var address2 in possibleAddresses) {
```

should be

```
foreach (var address2 in possibleAddresses2) {
```